# How do I create a Spring @ExceptionHandler method that does not log a WARN message to the log

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with a Spring `@ExceptionHandler` that mostly does what I want.  It sets the HTTP status code to 409 and includes extra error information in the JSON response.

```
@ExceptionHandler(PolicyExecutionException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(PolicyExecutionException se){
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(se.getScriptErrorMap());
}
```

What I've noticed is that even though it delivers the correct response to the client, the Spring is logging a message at the WARN level.  My message is quite long and only relevant to the client.  I'd rather not log it at all on the server side.  Can this be turned off?

> 2017-06-19 18:48:10,659 [p-nio-8060-exec-2] WARN
> o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved exception
> caused by Handler execution:

One alternative I have used is to catch the `PolicyExecutionException` on each of the Controller methods where it could be thrown.  This leads to extra boilerplate I'd rather avoid if possible.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: do you want to turn off only this specific logs of exception handler? one alternative is to change the logging level to ERROR.

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring Boot.  I may end up going down the path of changing the log level to error for this category.  If possible, I would rather just tell Spring to not log any Warning for this one Exception.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your exception handler that is how the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` works. If you don't want that that component logs, disable logging for it (or set it to ERROR).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.html), a supertype of `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`, maintains a `warnLogger` for logging that message when an exception is resolved, controlled by [`setWarnLogCategory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.html#setWarnLogCategory-java.lang.String-).

> Default is no warn logging. Specify this setting to activate warn
>   logging into a specific category. Alternatively, override the
>   `logException(java.lang.Exception,
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)` method for custom logging.

When you create your `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` (or when it's created for you through default configuration), it's set to `null` and not used.

With Spring Boot, you can control whether it's enabled with the

```
spring.mvc.logResolvedException
```

application property. This controls the corresponding value in [`WebMvcProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcProperties.html#setLogResolvedException-boolean-). (It's `false` by default so you must have set it to `true` in your configuration, or you've called `setWarnLogCategory` explicitly.)

---

Alternatively, turn off the logger.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Setting `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=false` does turn off this logging.  Even though it does it for all Exceptions, its probably good enough for me.  I also just tracked down how my  configuration was logging this warning even though I never explicitly turned on this logging.  I am using Spring dev-tools and it sets this property to true in its DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.

Comment: @Gary Note that comment in Javadoc about overriding `logException` for specific `Exception` types. You wouldn't have to implement any other behavior.

Comment: `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception` is `false` by default, but spring-boot-devtools set it to `true`, maybe for easier debugging in development. See [DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/env/DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.java#L58). So you may not need to set it.